# I would like the Arrays to remember it all

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

This is about my assignment so I would appreciate generic answers with explanation.

I have a for-loop which I have to make for an online ordering system. The for-loop and ordering all works fine but if the same item is put in twice, then it forgets the previous order for the same item and only remembers the latest one. I am required to use simple arrays and for-loops so I would appreciate if the solution/help was also of this basic level.

My code looks something like this (NOTE: The following is just an example of what part of the loop looks like--this is not a complete program):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //I changed the loop so there's no confusion about
                              //what I am actually asking about.
    if (order.equalsIgnoreCase(computer) {
         int price = quantity[i] + itemcode;
    }
}
```

To explain further, this loop and the if statement work perfectly if a certain item is only ordered once. But if the user enters, say, an order for a computer once and then after 3 more orders, orders another computer, then the output does not add the previous order in the new order but only remembers the latest one.

I would appreciate any work around suggested for this but again, since this is for my studies, I would appreciate explanations rather than direct solutions.

Please ask me questions in case this is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "forgets the previous order"?

Comment: I don't think I understand the `blah == blah` part. What exactly are you trying to do here? Post more code.

Comment: Dave, for example, if the user ordered 4 computers first, then orders 10 more computers, the program does not compute that to 14, but only takes into account the latter order, which is for 10 computers.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; true; i++)` - it is more common to omit the condition in infinite for-loops, `for (int i = 0;; ++i)`.

Comment: @nickecarlo using for-loop the way you use it is asking for trouble

Comment: The looping forever is not the problem here, the problem is with the ordering system. I want the program to retain all the ordering information and in the end add it all together for the final invoice. I actually didn't know about omitting the condition for infinite loops, I am pretty new at Java (or programming as a whole).

Comment: What is the "price" variable? you only set it, is that supposed to be like that? Since any value you've set it to previously will be overritten.

Comment: @soulcheck could you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @nickecarlo I've written that before your edit. It had an out of bounds exception waiting to be thrown from the inside of your loop. Now it's ok. Although you should still make it somehow connected to length of `quantity` array, since that's what you're indexing.

Comment: You are talking about the array all the time, but not showing where it's declared and how it's used. How we supposed to know why it's not remembering the orders?

Comment: Please post more code if you answer did not help. If you can, just post everything.

Comment: If you really want a solution you need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Otherwise your question is so vague it is impossible to actually figure out what is going on just by you describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Forgets" suggests that you are overwriting something in your code rather than, say, just incrementing. Go through your code, see what parts of it gets reset when you place a new order. For instance, if you are doing

`quantity[1] = getNumberFromUser("How many apples?");`

then this would obviously *erase* the old value each time. If you want to merely increment the number of apples, do something like

`quantity[1] += getNumberFromUser("How many apples?");`

Another general advice is to use print statements to debug your code. That way you can see for  yourself what really happens. Learning to use a real debugger would also be of great benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try it out. I haven't posted the whole code because it is my college assignment and a lot of the students use this website for help. THey are very strict with plagiarism and I don't want to risk anything. Let me try your suggestion and then I will let you know where it goes.

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking for. Thanks! Its pretty basic but I have virtually no experience in programming so I can get stuck sometimes.

Comment: Just to be clear, all I had to do was change the '=' to '+='. All the experienced programmers are probably thinking "oh what a noob", but it really is hard for someone like me who has never taken programming but now has to, because of college.

Comment: We are glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

if you have two or more typres of products and want to calculate the price for all the orders together then you can try the following code,, i think thats very simple,,

```
int price=0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //I changed the loop so there's no confusion about
                              //what I am actually asking about.
    if (order.equalsIgnoreCase(computer) {
          price += quantity[i] + itemcode; //use the previous value of price
    }
}
```

or else if you want to have history for each product separately then you have to try the same with a array of price for each product type..
If you cant get the answer then comment here,,